# Android: Bluetooth LE connection terminates automatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm testing a  Bluetooth LE connection between two Android devices (Nexus 6 with Android 6.0 and Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 5.1). The Nexus is setup as the Peripheral and the Samsung connects as the central. The connection is always correctly established but then the connection is closed after a few seconds without any apparent reason. This is the GattServerCallback code:

```
  public class MyServerCallBack extends BluetoothGattServerCallback
{


    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);


        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {


         Log.i(TAG,"SOMEONE CONNECTED TO OUR SERVER "+device.getName()+" "+device.getAddress());


        }

        else if (newState== BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED)
        {

            Log.i(TAG,"SOMEONE DISCONNECTED FROM OUR SERVER");
        }


    }

}
```

And this is the BluetoothGattCallback for the central:

public class MyCallBack extends BluetoothGattCallback
    {

```
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

        if (status!=133)
        {

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {


                if (mConnectionState!=STATE_CONNECTED)
                {

                    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;

                    }




            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {



                Log.i(TAG, "RECEIVED DISCONNECTED SIGNAL.");

            }

        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"STATUS IS 133");
            //gatt.close();
            //gatt.connect();
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            mDiscoveryState = STATE_IDLE;

        }

    }
```

A few seconds after establishing a connection. The log will indicate a disconnection without any apparent reason. Is this a known bug for Android?

Comment: Have you tried sending some data every 1 second or so and see what happens? Maybe some internal "no activity" timeout is set.

Comment: What are you trying to do after connection is done? What services are you adding on the server side. 

Print the status on both side. and share the outcome here

Comment: @AANKIT: After establishing the connection: Discover services -> Get characteristic -> Write characteristic. The log output from the client is: /BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=19 clientIf=9 device=66:76:05:11:D3:AD

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt Hey. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @Muddz yes. When your gatt connection is successful, you have to also establish a connection from your BluetoothGattServer with BluetoothDevice.connect().

Comment: Roberto, can you please post your code solution and mark it with the green checkmark? I am having a similar problem, but your comment about calling connect again doesn't seem to make sense, when you have already been successful in establishing a connection.

Comment: @AAnkit and everyone else .. have you guys figured this out ?